# Openssl: Verify RSA encrypted data with public key in certificate

Tags: openssl, rsa, encryption

I have a base64 encoded digital signature in a file called digital_signatue1.txt:

```
LE3v7aHDOtCYEWrURYfxrq4tAx5zg0siBK0yBdYJTxWTFw/tLoEOcT0JZPRy8RMY
bkCuLClsdVnjYhyfots3RyVl4uaSd2gpEnIN6YCo/DBCBltfWri3rFwtSeV/Gm9K
4+fMNiziTYjUWFS+1v1rbFxv4MbsRFEfYEtU0+xVHN8=
```

To base64 decode this digital signature, I used the following command:

```
openssl base64 -d -in digital_signature1.txt -out digital_signature2.txt
```

Then to verify that the digital signature was signed by the sender, I used the following command:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey sender-cert.pem -certin -in digital_signature2.txt
```

However, it gives me the following output:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
RSA operation error
4080:error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not     01:./crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:100:
4080:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check     failed:./crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c:699:
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I finally figured it out.  It turns out I wasn't using the sender's actual certificate but someone else's certificate after the "-inkey" option.  Oops!

Answer (score 0):

As per theory of signature verification, it requires following:
1. Data which is signed.
2. Signature of data
3. Public key.

Here, you have signature and public key, but my doubt is that where is the data?
Data must lies in digital_signature2.txt which is signed by using rsautl. Please check if digital_signature2.txt is well formed.